# Python 2.7 print statement “SyntaxError: invalid syntax”

Tags: python, syntax-error

My python version is: Python 2.7 (r27:82525, Jul  4 2010, 07:43:08) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

I'm getting a message called "Syntax Error| There's an error in your program: invalid syntax"

The 7 in Python 2.7 is highlighted red.

My code is:

```
Python 2.7 (r27:82525, Jul  4 2010, 07:43:08) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np

def graphRawFX () :
date,bid,ask = np.loadtxt('GPBUSD1d.txt'), unpack=True,
                          delimiter=',',
                          converters={0:mdates.strpdate2num('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') }
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((40,40), (0,0), rowspan=40, colspan=40)

ax1.plot(date,bid)
ax1.plot(date,ask)

ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first two lines are not Python code; they are just introductory text when you start the interpreter. Remove them from the script, as it appears you copy-and-pasted too much from an example. Once you've done that, you'll also need to fix your indentation, as at least one of the lines following the `def graphRawFX()` line needs to be indented.

Comment: Thanks, could you tell me how to indent? Any links at all would be definitely helpful.

Comment: @user1566769: see [this link](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#first-steps-towards-programming), look at the example then go down to the third point. Indenting works the same for function definitions (using `def`).